# Batch Apex conflicts and design?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I need help with a design issue and what happens in Batch Apex.

This is the scenario we have:
We have a territory object, then when you update a single field needs to update a field on UPTO hundreds of thoursands of contacts. To do this, I am using Batch Apex. And invoking it on the territory record before it’s updated.

Question:

1. Say the user updates the territory from A to B, and clicks save. This causes a big batch of contacts to get updated and  take a while Then, he changes B to C.   Are we guaranteed that the final update on all  impacted records will be C?    How come?
2. Or, is there a way to schedule your batch jobs?  I’m looking into asyncApexJob and using that as a framework…
3. Is there a better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Batch Apex doesn't work the same way a Trigger works. The only way the situation described in your Question 1 would occur is if you were to call/execute a batch from a Trigger, and I would highly recommend avoiding that, if it's even possible.
2. (and 3.) Batches are typically scheduled to run over-night, or during off hours, using the [Apex Scheduler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_scheduler.htm). This is the recommended solution.

Comment: Hey Matt- in response to 1, that's how I was calling my batch... Why do you want to avoid that?  In response to 2&3, I'm looking into the scheduler now. This is my design:

Comment: @ Matt- F/U Questions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067581/apex-scheduler-what-if-scenerios

Comment: If you were to execute the batch from a Trigger on the Territory object, there is a possibility that two batches could be running at the same time for a Territory record. I believe this would be undesirable in your case because the results (for the Contacts) would be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to put the logic in the AFTER UPDATE trigger on the Territory object, not the BEFORE UPDATE section.  As a general rule, if you need to update a field or value on the record/object that the trigger action is for (i.e. the Territory object in your case) then you use the BEFORE UPDATE or BEFORE INSERT section(s), and if you want to create/update/delete other records/objects (i.e. Contacts in your case) you use the AFTER UPDATE or AFTER INSERT section(s).

Second, I do not think there is anything wrong with initiating the batch apex process from your trigger.

For example, let us say you have a batch class called "BatchUpdateContactsBasedOnTerritory."  And this class has three (3) key features:

1. it implements "Database.Stateful" in addition to "Database.Batchable"
2. it has a constructor method that takes a list of territories as an argument/parameter
3. it has a member variable to hold the list of territories that are passed in

**Part of your batch class**:

```
global list<Territory> TerritoryList;

global BatchUpdateContactsBasedOnTerritory(list<Territory> updatedTerritories){
    TerritoryList = updatedTerritories;
}
```

**Your trigger**:

```
trigger TerritoryTrigger on Territory (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update)
{
    if(trigger.isInsert)
    {
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            // before insert event not implemented 
        }
        else if(Trigger.isAfter){
            // after insert event not implemented 
        }
    }else if(trigger.isUpdate){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            // before update event not implemented 
        }
        else if(Trigger.isAfter){
            // after update event - call batch class to process 1000 records at a time
            Database.ExecuteBatch(new BatchUpdateContactsBasedOnTerritory(trigger.new),1000);
        }
    }else if(trigger.isDelete){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            // before delete event not implemented 
        }
        else if(Trigger.isAfter){ 
            // after delete event not implemented 
        }
    }
    else if(Trigger.isUnDelete){ 
        // undelete event not implemented
    }
}
```