# apex scheduler- what if scenarios?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, scheduler

I'm looking into using apex scheduler to run a batch job. We can run it whenever we want, say 3 am when traffic is low, but I'm trying to anticipate some 'Oh-Crap' Scenarios. Can you guys help answer these questions for me?

**Setup:**

When the user modifies a territory 100k's of records can get updated.

**Questions:**

1. What are some scenarios that can realistically cause my jobs to not terminate?   I thought of a scenario of- when a user is editing a contact  which happens to be in one of the batches is being run.
2. What are some good practices for dealing with jobs that don't terminate?  I was thinking about scheduling another batch job 2 hours after this one, but I don't see my boss liking that.  I thought about maybe doing something in the finish() method- but don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any error in a batch will stop that batch from finishing correctly.
2. I suggest you do some kind of check to know that you processed everything. What I usually use for batches is to mark somehow the records that need processing to distinguish them from the ones that don't. When I finish processing a batch, I mark the records as processed. Then you can check in the finish() method if any record still needs processing and reschedule the batch to run again.

Comment: Thanks Acuriano. I had an idea for #2 In my batch class, my start method returns 100k's of contacts. in my execute, i was thinking about locking the records in the batch using the FOR UPDATE (see link). Is this good practice? or am I going to create problems for myself?
 
http://pastebin.com/qxVVxJCi

Comment: As it's always the case with locking mechanisms, you need to be careful with user's not being able to work and deadlocks. If you run the batch job in timeslot that no user is working, then you shouldn't have a problem. If you can't guarantee a time where with no usage, then try to make locks as short as possible. And be sure to handle any error correctly. For more information, see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm